# Why container can't request to another?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I can't send http query from container to another

I already try create network but it isn't helped

```
version: '2'
services:
 backend:
    container_name: backend
    image: registry.gitlab.com/myproject/backend:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 10083:3000
    networks:
      - dpnet
 widget-ws:
    container_name: widget-ws
    image: registry.gitlab.com/myproject/widget-ws:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 10084:3001
    networks:
      - dpnet
networks:
  dpnet:
    driver: bridge
```

I use container_name insteed url
`http://widget-ws:10084`
but got error
`connect ECONNREFUSED 172.21.0.2:10084`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the url: `http://widget-ws:3001`

Containers talk to each other on internal ports not the ones mapped to your host.

It is not necessary to create the network.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're mixing internal IPs with the ports you've opened to the host. Replace `http://widget-ws:10084` with `http://widget-ws:3001` and your connections should work.

Comment: But can I use external port without create network?

Answer (score 0):

The type of network a container uses, whether it is a bridge, an overlay, a macvlan network, or a custom network plugin, is transparent from within the container. So use the container port instead of using outer binded port.

```
http://widget-ws:3001
```